# Placing HTML page as content within JQuery Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox. http://fancybox.net

The problem I am having is in passing an HTML page as content into Fancybox. I see the link options, but not sure how to pass HTML. Can anybody help me out?

```
------- Adding code below

function test() {
    $.fancybox($.extend(fancyboxdefaults(), {
        wrapCSS: 'default',
        'content': 'static/common_structure.html',
        'afterShow' : function () {
            $("h2").html('Thank you');
            $("p").html('Thank you for your response.');
        }
    }) );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It probably depends on *how* you are doing it... so, how do you do it currently? Looking at the page, I can see an Ajax and iframe example... what don't you understand?

Comment: you could try using iframe option with fancybox, can you provide some code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Have anybody tried? You must be kidding... Have you read instructions and looked at demo http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ ?

Comment: The examples on the page you link work just fine (and I've used it this way myself). Unless you actually tell us specifically what the problem is, we can't help.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation page http://fancybox.net/howto is pretty good and explaining how to use it.

If you mean displaying HTML in a Fancybox then this will work:

```
<a href="http://www.example?iframe">This goes to iframe</a>

or

<a class="iframe" href="http://www.example">This goes to iframe</a>
```

If you want to create HTML to be passed to it then the following should work:

```
$('#my_page').fancybox({ 
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'overlayOpacity': 0.1,
        'showCloseButton'   : false,
        'content' : '<p>your html here</p>'
    });
```

Comment: Thanx todd for your response. for most of places, ajax response is fine with with me. only certain places I want to use common template and previously I was using "content":"template.html" but now seems like it stopped working. So just got confuse how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with fancybox Ajax or Iframe and load your HTML page into box.

Comment: Thanks to all!! Ajax response works very fine with me. I am facing problem with passing direct html file link which was working very fine in old lightbox. like 'content':'html/fancybox_alerts.html' where html file is common template.